# How to use custom scoring function in sklearn cross_val_score

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I want to use **Adjusted Rsquare** in the `cross_val_score` function. I tried with `make_scorer` function but it is not working.

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_tr, X_test, y_tr, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

regression = LinearRegression(normalize=True)
from sklearn.metrics.scorer import make_scorer
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
def adjusted_rsquare(y_true,y_pred):
    adjusted_r_squared = 1 - (1-r2_score(y_true, y_pred))*(len(y_pred)-1)/(len(y_pred)-X_test.shape[1]-1)
    return adjusted_r_squared

my_scorer = make_scorer(adjusted_rsquare, greater_is_better=True)
score = np.mean(cross_val_score(regression, X_tr, y_tr, scoring=my_scorer,cv=crossvalidation, n_jobs=1))
```

It is trowing an error:

```
IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds
```

Is there any way to use my custom function i.e; `adjusted_rsquare` with `cross_val_score`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`adjusted_rsquare(X,Y)` is a number, it's not a function, just create the scorer like this:

```
my_scorer = make_scorer(adjusted_rsquare, greater_is_better=True)
```

You also need to [change the score function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html):

```
def adjusted_rsquare(y_true, y_pred, **kwargs):
```

That's the prototype that you should use. You compare the actual result to the result it should have been.

Comment: I have changed the code little bit and tried with what you have suggested but it is not working and throwing an error like positional indexes are out of bounds.

Comment: Added a comment on the wrong function declaration, you don't do any prediction inside the function, that's tackled by the model you want to score.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to get y_pred from cross_val_score?

Comment: That's the job of `cross_val_score` to give you y_true and y_pred. That's what you get in your function. You get them by definition.

Comment: I changed and tried again but still facing same issue.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for your help